# Stata: Keep only observations with minimum, maximum and median value of a given variable

Tags: select, stata, vlookup

In Stata, I have a dataset with two variables: `id` and `var`, and say 1000 observations. The variable `var` is of type `float` and takes distinct values for all observations. I would like to keep only the three observations where var is either the minimum of var, the maximum of var, or the median of var.

The way I currently do this:

```
summarize var, detail
local varmax = r(max)
local varmin = r(min)
local varmedian= r(p50)
keep if inlist(float(var),float(`varmax') , float(`varmedian'), float(`varmin'))
```

The problem that I face is that sometimes the `inlist` condition will not match one of the value. E.g. I end up with two observations instead of three, for instance the one with min and the one with max, but not the one with median. I suspect this has to do with a precision problem. As you see, I tried to convert all numbers to float, but this is apparently not sufficient.

Any fix to my solution, or alternative solution would be greatly appreciated (if possible without installing additional packages), thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not in the first instance a precision problem.

It is an inevitable problem when (1) the number of values is even and (2) the median is the mean of two central values that are different. Then the median itself is not a value in the dataset and will not be found by `keep`.

Consider a data set 1, 2, 3, 4. The median 2.5 is not in the data. This is very common; indeed it is what is expected with all values distinct and the number of observations even.

Other problems can arise because two or even three of the minimum, median and maximum could be equal to each other. This is not your present problem, but it can bite with other variables (e.g. indicator variables).

Precision problems are possible.

Here is a general solution purported to avoid all these difficulties.

If you `collapse` to min, median. max and then `reshape` you can avoid the problem. You will always get three results, even if they are numerically equal and/or not present in the data.

In the trivial example below, the identifier is needed only to appease `reshape`. In other problems, you might want to `collapse` using `by()` and then your identifier comes ready-made. However, you will be less likely to want to `reshape` in that case.

```
. clear

. set obs 4
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 4

. gen y = _n

. collapse (min)ymin=y (max)ymax=y (median)ymedian=y

. gen id = _n

. reshape long y, i(id) j(statistic) string 
(note: j = max median min)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        1   ->       3
Number of variables                   4   ->       3
j variable (3 values)                     ->   statistic
xij variables:
                      ymax ymedian ymin   ->   y
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. list 

     +---------------------+
     | id   statis~c     y |
     |---------------------|
  1. |  1        max     4 |
  2. |  1     median   2.5 |
  3. |  1        min     1 |
     +---------------------+
```

All that said, having (lots of?) datasets with just three observations sounds poor data management strategy. Perhaps this is extracted from some larger question.

UPDATE

Here is another way to keep precisely 3 observations. Apart from the minimum and maximum, we use the rule that we keep the "low median", i.e. the lower of two values averaged for the median, when the number of observations is even, and a single value that is the median otherwise. (In Stephen Stigler's agreeable terminology, we can talk of "comedians" in the first case.)

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. sort mpg

. drop if missing(mpg)
(0 observations deleted)

. keep if inlist(_n, 1, cond(mod(_N, 2), ceil(_N/2), floor(_N/2)), _N)
(71 observations deleted)

. l mpg

     +-----+
     | mpg |
     |-----|
  1. |  12 |
  2. |  20 |
  3. |  41 |
     +-----+
```

`mod(_N, 2)` is 1 if `_N` is odd and 0 if `_N` is even. The expression in `cond()` selects `ceil(_N/2)` if the number of observations is odd and `floor(_N/2)` if it is even.

Comment: Of course, I'm silly, I hadn't thought that it could be a median problem with an even number of observerations! Unfortunately I cannot use your solution as I need to identify the observations corresponding to those values. Is there an elegant way that I could choose for the median the observation closest to the median value from below?

Comment: I will extend my answer.